# I need help calibrating color across multiple programs

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, adobe-photoshop, colors, gimp

I have recently gotten a new computer, and I am having trouble calibrating the color. Up until this point, the color in the web browser is accurate, and continues to be for most images, but I am having trouble with one image. The top left pixel in different programs are:

Chrome: b47540

Firefox: b47540

Gimp: ad844a

Photoshop: a77a41

Windows photo viewer: a16b3b

Dreamweaver: a37a42

As you can see, these are huge differences. Can someone help me with this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What kind of image is it (bmp, jpg, png, etc.)?  Does the image have transparency?

Comment: I've tried exporting as jpg and png, same with both. Has no transparency, but I can wipe the alpha channel just to make sure. EDIT: No, didn't help.